# MiYodeya history: what sort of rabbinic guidance was given when creating the site?

Tags: discussion, pre-migration

Loewian made a very interesting comment below [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/87788/11501) when he wrote

> I believe the generally accepted Talmudic interpretation of "*Torah
>   tziva lanu moshe morasha kehilath Yaakov*" is that there are portions
>   of Torah that can only be shared between *Kehilath Yaakov* (those who
>   have accepted upon themselves all the mitzvot) and that sharing them
>   with *Bnei Noach* would be a serious violation of *halacha*.

Without discussing the specifics of this comment (I can see both pros and cons), this led me to wonder **what sort of rabbinic guidance and counseling was asked by the site creators before its creation?**

I imagine the standard disclaimer on not offering rabbinic advice could have come from there, but what if anything else was said at the time.

This is more historic curiosity than anything else but I believe it would be wonderful to have a record of these conclusions.

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/414/11501

Comment: How is our site different from Chabad.org or YUTorah.com? Anything posted publicly is available to gentiles too

Comment: @mbloch Your second comment links to the answer to this question. Also, that was for a different site, which I controlled. The one you're participating on now is the sole creation of Stack Overflow, Inc.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Thanks - I thought there might be more but now we know. Also agree with DoubleAA comment

Comment: One clear difference is that here you are answering questions directly to non-jews (possibly, if they are the questioner), while there you are giving it to Jews and he comes along and takes it, similar to R' Moshe Feinstein's psak about teaching gemara to girls.