# Rabbinical guidance of MiYodea

Tags: discussion

After seeing a couple of discussion on different ways of treating different aspects of this site - users, questions, answers, comments by its moderators, I was wondering if actual Rabbinical figures stand behind this site and influence the information flow.

Are there Rabbis that guide this site or it is fully communal?

Comment: Related, maybe duplicate: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4455/13438

Comment: @Alex Thanks, I'll trim my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1615/759 https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4522/759

Comment: @DoubleAA Thank you, an interesting question on its own. I'm used to the fact that in Israel most informational frameworks are guided (affiliated). So I'm interested to know if there are any Rabbis agreed on as maybe arbitrators by the "decision squad" / moderators of this site

Answer (score 5):

There is no formal rabbinical oversight on Mi Yodeya.  That's why it's especially important that we treat the site as a source of *information*, never *p'sak*.

Some participants here are rabbis.  I actually don't know if any moderators are rabbis; they haven't publicly declared.  Moderators moderate based on Stack Exchange rules and norms and common Jewish values, but we don't make a stronger statement.  (On Jewish values, I'm referring to editing or removing content that might be accepted on other sites but that violates our community norms about modesty, *lashon hara*, and so on.  I *don't* mean that we impose other kinds of religious restrictions.)

Answer (score 1):

It's obvious that there isn't rabbinical guidance, you see easily some differences between main participants.

But there is a common spirit between most people interested in Tora learning, an attachment to yeshiva learning value, Shas (or Shas only) Poskim, and rules of argumentation. Rules of argumentation are important in every serious site, even not Tora based.